# Array padding not right

Tags: spacing, arrays

I have the following array environment:

```
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & = & \text{some equation} \\
0 & = & \text{some other equation} \\
  & \vdots \\
0 & = & \text{last equation}
\end{array}
```

However, I get lots of spacing around the equal signs here, not unlike when using the eqnarray environment.

I want to use the array environment because \vdots is of smaller width than =, and gets centered under it.

Any help on conforming the padding/spacing to other equations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `mathtools` provides a `\vdotswithin` command exactly for this situation:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  0 &=  \text{some equation} \\
  0 &=  \text{some other equation} \\
    &\vdotswithin{=} \notag \\
  0 &=  \text{last equation}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate spacing in an `array` environment requires you to remove the default `array` column separation (`\arraycolsep`) and insert empty groups where needed so the binary relations/operators can space themselves. This is easily achieved via [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)'s `\newcolumntype`.

Below the new column type `C` inserts `{}` to the left (using `>`) and right (using `<`) of its contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c@{}C@{}c}
  a & = & \text{some equation} \\
  b & = & \text{some other equation} \\
    & \vdots \\
  c & = & \text{last equation}
\end{array}
\]

\begin{align*}
  a &= \text{some equation} \\
  b &= \text{some other equation} \\
    & \vdots \\
  c &= \text{last equation}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

While you're still left with padding on the `array` ends, it doesn't make a difference in terms of the alignment, as you can see in comparison to using `align`.

There are advantages to using `array` above `align`, but there are also drawbacks. One advantage is an easy alignment change to suit your needs compared to the fixed `r`ight-`l`eft alignment of `align`. However, `align` provides flexibility when you have multiple alignment points, together with interspersed text-capability, page-breakability, vertical spread-out-i-ness (somewhat achievable via `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` when using `array`), ... So, all-in-all, `align` works better.

Answer (score 2):

In this solution, I use the features of the `stackengine` package to create vertical stacks.  A "Long stack" as defined by the package, creates stacks whose inter-item baseline is constant and settable (default `\baselineskip`).  It can be told to stack its arguments in text mode (default) or math mode.

So this solution is composed of three stacks: a stack of right-aligned zeros (with a blank line where the `vdots` are; a stack of center-aligned equal signs with slightly-shifted `\vdots`, enclosed in a `\mathrel` for proper horizontal spacing; and a stack of left-aligned text sentences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\begin{document}
\[
\stackMath
\Longstack[r]{0\\0\\ \\0}
\mathrel{\Longstack{=\\=\\ \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\vdots}\\=}}
\stackText
\Longstack[l]{some equation\\some other equation\\ \\last equation}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: People who aren't already familiar with the `stackengine` package and its many capabilities would probably appreciate getting a couple of sentences that explain what your setup is all about.

Comment: @mico Good point, Mico.  Done.

Comment: this looks great, but ... consider the plight of a visually impaired reader, who must rely on an audio rendering.  unfortunately the important flow of the message is lost.  a way to keep the meaning more scrutable would be welcome.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Thank you for that comment.  It is the first time that issue has been brought to my attention, and I must admit I hadn't thought of it before.  Sad to say, I'm not sure that issue can be resolved with stacking as the methodology.